# Measure on the reduced Borel field of subsets of the Cantor space

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra

Let $X=2^\omega$ be the Cantor space, $B(X)$ the Borel field of $X$, and $M(X)$ the $\sigma$-ideal of meager subsets of $X$. Is it possible to define a measure on $B(X)/M(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The proof is essentially the same as the proof that there are meager sets of positive measure with respect to Lebesgue measure.

In detail, if $\mu$ is a measure on $B(X)/M(X)$, we can consider $\mu$ as a measure on $B(X)$ which vanishes on all meager sets.  Now let $\{q_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X$.  For each $n$, $\{q_n\}$ is meager and so must have measure $0$.  Picking a sequence of open neighborhoods $U_m$ of $q_n$ with $\bigcap_m U_m=\{q_n\}$, we must have $\mu(U_m)\to 0$.  In particular, we can pick $m$ such that $\mu(U_m)<2^{-n-1}$.  Let us write $V_n$ for this chosen $U_m$.

Now let $V=\bigcup_n V_n$.  Since $q_n\in V$ for all $n$, $V$ is an open dense set, and $X\setminus V$ is meager.  But $\mu(V)\leq\sum_n\mu(V_n)<\sum_n 2^{-n-1}<1$, so $\mu(X\setminus V)>0$.  This is a contradiction, and so no such $\mu$ can exist.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What if I "force it", so to speak, in the sense that $\mu(X\setminus V)=0$ if and only if $X\setminus V$ is meager? (I think spaces in which this hold are called "category measure spaces".)

Comment: @puzzled You can do that but not in a non-trivial way because, by Eric's proof, $\mu$ will be the $0$ measure. (I think it is implicit in Eric's argument that $\mu(X)=1$, though it clearly works whenever $\mu(X)>0$.) Incidentally, I believe that if you require $\mu$ to be only finitely (as opposed to countably) additive, then $\mu$ can be both non-trivial and assign measure $0$ to meager sets.

Comment: Thank you @aduh for your comment. Just to be sure, when you speak about the "0 measure", do you mean the measure which assigns 0 to all subsets of $B(X)/M(X)$?

Comment: @puzzled Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Usually when one speaks of a measure on an abstract Boolean $\sigma$-algebra this refers to a probability measure, i.e. a nonnegative measure where the total measure is $1$.  So that is what I assumed you meant.  Of course if you drop that requirement then you could always have the $0$ measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric and @aduh.

Comment: Sorry, I have one last question. Suppose that I settle for a finitely additive measure. Given the discussion above, would it make sense (or can I) extend it to be countably additive? In other words, is extending a finite measure to a sigma-additive measure an intermediate concept between the choice of either a finite or sigma-additive measure right from the start?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "extend".